# If $p \neq 2$ prime and $n \equiv r$ (mod $p-1$). then $2^n \equiv 2^r$ (mod $p$).

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was working through some computational drills and came across this very useful property.

> If $p \neq 2$ prime and $n \equiv r$ (mod $p-1$), then $2^n \equiv 2^r$ (mod $p$).

From Fermat's Little Theorem, we have

$2^{p-1} \equiv 1$ (mod $p$)

Now multiplying both sides by $2^r$, we have

$2^{r(p-1)} \equiv 2^r$ (mod $p$)

But from here I am not certain of how to get to the property stated above.

Comment: Oh my goodness I just realised my error, how embarrassing.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $n \geq r.$ Then 
$$ n = r + t(p-1)  $$
with integer $t \geq 0$

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say this but you need to be more secure with exponent laws!  If you have
$$2^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$$
and you multiply both sides by $2^r$ you get
$$2^{r+p-1}\equiv2^r\pmod p\ ,$$
not what you wrote above.

To prove it correctly, let $n=r+k(p-1)$.  Then
$$2^n=2^r(2^{p-1})^k\equiv2^r(1)^k\equiv2^r\pmod p\ .$$